# Using second momentum as part of new cost function? (Tensorflow and/or keras)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, mathematical-optimization

I'm currently trying to take Adam's second order moment term, v_t, and use that as an additional term in my cost function. How can I implement something like this:

```
Cost = Cross Entropy + v_t*some_function(weights)
```

Can this be accomplished within python? Or do I have to write my own C++ code to accomplish this? Also is this easily accomplished in a framework like Keras? 
Here's the code for the cost function that I'm trying to add into keras:

```
def my_loss(y_pred, y_true, current_weights, v_t):
     normal_loss=K.categorial_cross_entropy(y_pred,y_true)
     additional_term=K.dot(K.square(current_weights - K.some_function(current_weights)), v_t)
     return normal_loss + additional_term
```

Answer (score 2):

This would be problematic, regardless of what framework you did this with. Specifically, we have from the [ADAM paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.6980.pdf) the relevant lines:

```
g_t = d Cost / d weights
v_t = beta2 * v_{t-1} + (1 - beta2) g_t^2
```

Now, if you were to include v_t into Cost, this would be an implicit equation:

```
g_t = d Cross Entropy / d weights + d (v_t*some_function) / d weights
v_t = beta2 * v_{t-1} + (1 - beta2) g_t^2
```

Notice how v_t appears in both equations. We can expand it as such for greater clarity

```
v_t = beta2 * v_{t-1} + (1 - beta2) [d Cross Entropy / d weights + d (v_t*some_function) / d weights]^2
```

You could attempt to solve this exactly, but in doing so you would have to use some form of implicit solver, which will be very computationally costly. One way would be [fixed point iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration).

Comment: Hi Jonas, I appreciate your reply. I had tried to solve this out by hand and ended up in a similar situation to the third equation you show. I had a followup question, are you aware if any of the current frameworks support implicit solvers? Thanks!

Comment: Sadly I am not aware of any such framework, but you could wrap your own using either fixed point iteration.

Another option would be to state the problem of finding v_t as a minimization problem and solving it using a fixed number of iterations (e.g. using ADAM).

Regardless, it would be quite computationally intensive since you iterate inside the iterations, so to say.